# What to do when a Google Cloud SQL postgres server upgrade (to a bigger machine) takes considerably longer than "a few minutes"?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, google-cloud-sql

We upgraded our Google Cloud SQL postgres server to a bigger machine and the upgrade is not terminating. In our experience, this usually takes less than 5 minutes, but we'ven been waiting for about 1.5 hours now and nothing is happening. There are no logs after the server shut down(except for failed connection attempts). We cannot switch to the failover, because  there is already an operation in progress (namely the upgrade that's causing the problem in the first place). Restarting is disabled because the operation is in progress. It seems like there's nothing we can do right now, except maybe apply the last backup, though we're not sure if that's even possible while an operation is in progress.

Is there anything we can do to restart the DB or fix the problem?

Comment: I think that, after 2 hours, you should contact Support, just in case there was a malfunction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upgrade a CloudSQL server, the instance is rebooted.  It can happen occasionally that rebooting takes more than expected, which seems to be what happened to your server, but this is not unexpected behaviour.

This being said, be sure to check the [status](https://status.cloud.google.com/) of the CloudSQL service. And if upgrades get stuck too often or never finish, [contact support](https://cloud.google.com/support/).

To reduce the chances of having this issue again:

- [Configure High Availability](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ha) for your instance, so it has failover capability.
- Make sure that the maintenance window of failover replicas is different from that of the master instance. To change the maintenance schedule, on the GCP console, go to SQL, click on an instance, and "Edit maintenance schedule"->"Set maintenance schedule". Then choose a window.